# How to Convert a named json array to un named array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to convert following json array

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
    }]
}
```

to a json array without name 'Employee'

```
 {[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

using javascript

Comment: Now the format of the resulting object is not valid

Comment: `obj.employees` ; no transform or iteration needed.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var employeeArr =  {"employees":[
         {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
         {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
         {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
     ]}

var emp = $.each(employeeArr.employees, function(index , value){
                  return value;
            },{})

console.log(emp);
```

Comment: it works, but why do all that for no reason whatsoever?

Comment: @dandavis: my english is not so good ?? what are you asking i didnt understand in comment area Sorry for that

Comment: `var emp=employeeArr.employees;` gives the same as your each() routine...  ;) i can write `x=(2+3)` instead of `x=5`, but why?

Comment: these are different approches :) i have this one so .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply can do ,

```
var arr ={"employees":[
         {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
         {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
         {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
         ]};
var employee = arr.employees;
console.log(employee);
```